# Excel Object Library - app compiled using 16.0 and try to run using 12.0 on different computer

Tags: c#, excel, binding, com, .net-assembly

1. I have Computer A with Office 2016 installed - including Office COM libraries to develope apps - Excel Object Library was used to create an app (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel ver 15.0.0.0 included in GAC) - great, app works great.
2. I have computer B with Office 2007 installed - it includes Excel COM libraries in its GAC - ver 12.0.0.0 and ver 14.0.0.0. I want to run my app (from computer A) on this computer.
3. I added App.config file to my WPF app as follows:

   ```
     <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"
                             publicKeyToken="71e9bce111e9429c"
                             culture="neutral" />
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="15.0.0.0"
                            newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>

        <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="office"
                             publicKeyToken="71e9bce111e9429c"
                             culture="neutral" />
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="15.0.0.0"
                            newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>  
     </assemblyBinding>
   ```

So I am trying to use older version of both libraries on computer where older version of Office in installed. I read that it is possible to set older version as the value of newVersion="". I include myApp.exe.config in my deployment but app still screams that it seems Excel not installed.

4. My last resort would be to use a virtual machine with Office 2007 installed, download Visual Studio and recompile project updating references to older version of Excel Object Library - but maybe there is still another way to make my app work with Excel Object Library ver 12.0.0.0 on Computer B. I would be gratefull for any ideas before I decide to go with this 'virtual tank'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I simply removed \n from assemblyIdentity and bindingRedirect in App.config and it works now:

   ```
    <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" publicKeyToken="71e9bce111e9429c" culture="neutral" />
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="15.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>

    <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="office" publicKeyToken="71e9bce111e9429c" culture="neutral" />
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="15.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
   ```